# Knex.js: Can I put function in the raw Knex query?

Tags: javascript, database-migration, knex.js

I want to encrypt all the passwords in my Postgres database with knex migration. The first step is to extend the varchar from 64 to a larger number, this part works. The encryption part is supposed to be done with a function that is imported from the project. This is what I've tried:

```
const {encrypt} = require("/path/to/function")

exports.up = function(knex) {
    return knex.schema.table("users", function(table) {
        table.string("passhash", 500).alter(); # this is done no problem 
    }).then(() => {
        return knex.raw(`UPDATE users SET passhash = encrypt(passhash)`) # this is the idea I had, but it doesn't work
    });
};
```

So the idea is to first change the column type and then encrypt all the passwords with the function. Is this achievable?
I would appreciate any idea, as I couldn't find a similar usage of knex raw, or perhaps there is an entirely different way to approach this?

Comment: What is the output for knex.raw?

Comment: I just get an error during migration: migration failed with error: UPDATE users SET passhash = encrypt(passhash); - function encrypt(character varying) does not exist

Answer (score 0):

You can't run a js function as a DB one...

You will need to pull the users table, make the change to the password field, and save it back.

```js
const {encrypt} = require('/path/to/function');

exports.up = function (knex) {
  return knex.schema
    .table('users', function (table) {
      table.string('passhash', 500).alter();
    })
    .then(async () => {
      const users = await knex('users');
      const promises = users.map((user) => {
        const passhash = encrypt(user.passhash);
        return knex.update('users').set({passhash}).where('id', user.id);
      });

      return Promise.all(promises);
    });
};
```